# AWS dynamodb query with multiple conditions on same key - in php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to query aws dynamodb with multiple conditions on same key as here under.
But I get error:

> Invalid operator used in KeyConditionExpression: OR

What is the right way to resolve this?

```
'ExpressionAttributeNames' => array (
            '#user' => 'user',
            '#attr1' =>  'attr',
            '#attr2' =>  'attr'
        ),
        'ExpressionAttributeValues' =>  array (
            ':user' => array('S' => "$id"),
            ':attr1' => array('S' => 'image'),
            ':attr2' => array('S' => 'video')
        ),
        'KeyConditionExpression' => ' (#attr1 = :attr1  or #attr2 = :attr2 ) and #user = :user  ',
        'Select' => 'ALL_ATTRIBUTES',
         "ReturnConsumedCapacity"=> "TOTAL",
         "Limit"=>10,
```

Comment: I thing you need to use BatchGetItem instead of query

Comment: Thanks a Tonne for this.